# My simple rewrite rule does not work

Tags: mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/$ index.php?r=contest&id=$1
```

I have want to rewrite

```
localhost/index.php?r=contest&id=1
```

to

```
localhost/contest/1
```

Above is the rewrite rule that i came out. Initially i thought it will work, but apparently it does not. can anyone guide me on the mistake?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule in your question is using back reference $1 to `contest` in the first regex group, instead of $2 to the 2nd group with `1`.

You may try this instead:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? index.php?r=contest&id=$2 [L,NC]
```

Or:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? index.php?r=$1&id=$2 [L,NC]
```

OPTION:

The rule using only one parameter should be like this, assuming it is a dynamic string:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/? index.php?r=$1 [L,NC]
```

#### UPDATE with a complete rule-set:

Request example: `localhost/contest/1`

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f  [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . - [L]

# 2 parameters. Both dynamic.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php   [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ index.php?r=$1&id=$2 [L,NC]

# 1 dynamic parameter.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php   [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ index.php?r=$1   [L,NC]
```

Comment: I updated my answer explaining the problem and making some modifications. Maybe you want to give it a try.

Comment: Hi, thanks now it works! however, my rewrite url for localhost/index.php?r=contest will not work for localhost/contest anymore.. how to i make both type of rewrite work tgt?

Comment: I don't quite understand. Do you want to pass only `contest` instead of 2 parameters? If so, is `contest` a fixed or a dynamic string?

Comment: i am sorry, i made a mistake, it is affecting other pages like localhost/index.php?r=home -> localhost/home ...

Comment: This is the two statement i have now.. RewriteRule ^(.*)/ index.php?r=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/? index.php?r=contest&id=$2 [L,NC]

Comment: I updated my answer with one rule for one parameter only. Hope that's what you need.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the fast response, when i put both together, it seems it conflict with each other.. doesnt work

Comment: Okay. I am starting to understand. I will modify my answer with a complete rule-set for 1 and 2 parameters.

Comment: thank you! it works like a charm! i would like to learn more about how to derive these statement.. would you mind giving me some explanation to guide me along?

Comment: From your rule, I think you already know the basics. Back references are numbered according to the group position in the regex, except $0 that gets the whole *CondPattern*. The Options directive is mandatory. The most important thing to remember is rules are parsed several times regardless of the **L** flag, so preventing loops with conditions like those above the rules are necessary. The first 2 conditions make sure existing files and directories are served and excluded from the following rules.

Answer (score 0):

here is a really good doc on [cleaning your url's](http://wettone.com/code/clean-urls)